# Weird horizontal line through menu item after device rotation in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

After rotating device several times I noticed weird horizontal line through "All Sites" item in the main menu:

> [image: All sites line]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)